# Replace numbers on even positions in sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, sorting

I have an array sorted in ascended order. I want to replace the biggest **`m`** numbers found even positions in the array with 0.

My algorithm that I thought looks like this:

```
k=1;
for j=n:1  %%starting from last position to first
    if(rem(j,2)==0 && (k<=m))  %%checking if the position is even & not getting over m numbers
        B(j) = 0;
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
```

Can anyone point out why it is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://ideone.com/TftNwp) should do the trick. This works for vectors with both odd and even number of elements.

```
n = numel(B);
B((n-mod(n,2)):-2:(n-mod(n,2)-2*M)) = 0
```

or

```
n = mod(numel(B),2);
B((end-n:-2:end-n-2*M)) = 0
```

I prefer [Shai's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012372/1714410), but if your vector is **huge**, and `M` is relatively small, I would go with this approach, as it avoids creating a vector of length `numel(B)/2`

Answer (score 1):

A bit more complex

```
even = (n-rem(n,2)) : -2 : 1; % even indices in descending order
B( even(1:m) ) = 0; % set to zero
```

Note how `n-rem(n,2)` ensures that we start from the last **even** index into `B`.

PS,
It is best [not to use `j` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).